# Moving up a directory

Tags: php, linux, filesystems, dir

I'm creating a directory in a php script, moving into that directory and doing some stuff. This part works fine.

Now, I want to move out of this directory and delete it.
Any pointers on how to do this?

I have tried moving up 1 level, but it doesnt work

```
chdir("../");
chdir("..")
system("cd ..");
```

none of the above have any effect on the present working directory

Comment: What do you mean "moving into that directory"? Have you verified that? Also, there's no need to move into any directory (you can simply use longer paths).

Comment: `chdir("../")` should be fine. Expand on "it doesnt work".

Comment: @Jon Yes, I am able to move into the directory (verified with getcwd())

Comment: @Tomalak  It worked now. Had some other errors in the script because of which this command didnt execute

Comment: Error log output? Error reporting settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this to be more explicit about your intended paths:

```
$cwd = getcwd(); // remember the current path
chdir(<your target path>);
chdir($cwd); // go back to the inital working directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't chdir into that directory once you create it, modify files from outside it, and then remove it.

i.e. instead of doing something like:

```
mkdir("dir");
chdir("dir");
write_file("one");
write_file("two");
```

structure your code as:

```
mkdir("dir");
write_file("dir/one");
write_file("dir/two");
```

You then don't need to walk the directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against actually changing dir; simply hold the path of interest and operate upon it (and the files within it) directly.

That said, `chdir ('../');` should work.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a directory on the upper level like this

```
<?
   mkdir('../newdir/', 0755);
?>
```

without move in it